# How to add elements in vector together based on info from another vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector

I have two vector structs, one contains the codes and cost for each, and another is just orders that contains requested codes and totalCost (to be calculated)

vector parts(codes, cost);

vector orders(codes, totalCost); //totalCost set to 0;

where the parts vector contains something like ('A', 10, 'B', 20);

Where A and B are parts, 10 is cost for A, 20 cost for B.

and the orders vector contains orders such as A,B,C or just A,B Say we receive an order of parts A and B.

how do we go about adding these two based on cost from parts and storing the result in a new int that we gonna use later to add to the vector struct orders (totalCost).

I was trying for several hours, I think I need to use std::transform and maybe std::accumulate? just not sure how to put the two together...

This is what I have written so far:

```
int totalCost;
for(auto i : customers){
    for(auto x : parts){
      totalCost = accumulate(i.partsList.begin(), i.partsList.end(), ???);
      //then need to store cost for each order for use later
}
```

I have also tried:

```
void test(){
    int cost;
    for(unsigned i =0; i < customers.size(); i++){
        for(unsigned x=0; x < partsVec.size(); x++){
            for(unsigned z=0; z < customers.at(i).partsList.size(); z++){

                if(partsVec.at(x).code == customers.at(i).partsList.at(z)){
                    cost += partsVec.at(x).cost;
                    customers.at(i).cost= cost;
                }
            }
        }
    }
      for(auto i : customers){
        cout << i.cost<< endl;
    }
}
```

This output this:

```
40 //this is correct.

80 //this is incorrect, needs to be 40 as both customers have ordered same parts!
```

As you can see, this keeps incriminating and I can't figure out a way to stop it.

what I am trying to do, is get the total cost of all parts in partsList based on info from the parts vector. Customers vector has another vector of chars in it called partsList, then I can change the totalCost of each order to value obtained from above using accumulate or some other algorithm

Comment: provide all your variables definitions please

Comment: Let's see what you've been working on. For all we know you have a tiny mistake on line 42 that can be brushed off in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```cpp
struct Part
{
    char code;
    double cost;

    Part(char code, double cost)
        : code(code), cost(cost)
    {
    }
};

std::vector<Part> parts;

double costOfPart(char code)
{
    for(const Part &part : parts)
    {
        if (part.code == code)
            return part.cost;
    }
    return 0.0;
}

struct OrderItem
{
    char partCode;
    size_t quantity;

    OrderItem(char partCode, size_t quantity)
        : partCode(partCode), quantity(quantity)
    {
    }
};

struct Order
{
    int code;
    std::vector<OrderItem> items;

    Order(int code)
       : code(code)
    {
    }

    void addItem(char partCode, size_t quantity)
    {
        for (OrderItem &item : items)
        {
            if (item.partCode == partCode)
            {
                item.quantity += quantity;
                return;
            }
        }
        items.push_back(OrderItem(partCode, quantity));
    }

    double totalCost() const
    {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (const OrderItem &item : items)
        {
            total += (costOfPart(item.partCode) * item.quantity);
        }
        // TOOD: fees, taxes, discounts, etc...
        return total;
    }
};

std::vector<Order> orders;

double costOfAllOrders()
{
    double total = 0.0;
    for(const Order &order : orders)
    {
        total += order.totalCost();
    }
    return total;
}

double costOfOrder(int orderCode)
{
    for(const Order &order : orders)
    {
        if (order.code == orderCode)
            return order.totalCost();
    }
    return 0.0;
}

...

parts.push_back(Part('A', 10.0));
parts.push_back(Part('B', 20.0));

...

Order order(12345);
order.addItem('A', 1);
orders.push_back(order);

...

double costOfOneOrder = costOfOrder(12345);
double totalCostOfOrders = costOfAllOrders();
...
```

Or, if you really want to use `std::accumulate()`, then you can do something like this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

struct Part
{
    char code;
    double cost;

    Part(char code, double cost)
        : code(code), cost(cost)
    {
    }
};

std::vector<Part> parts;

double costOfPart(char code)
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(parts.begin(), parts.end(),
        [=](Part &part){ return part.code == code; }
    );
    if (iter != parts.end())
        return iter->cost;
    return 0.0;
}

struct OrderItem
{
    char partCode;
    size_t quantity;

    OrderItem(char partCode, size_t quantity)
        : partCode(partCode), quantity(quantity)
    {
    }
};

struct Order
{
    int code;
    std::vector<OrderItem> items;

    Order(int code)
       : code(code)
    {
    }

    void addItem(char partCode, size_t quantity)
    {
        auto iter = std::find_if(items.begin(), items.end(),
            [=](OrderItem &item){ return item.partCode == partCode; }
        );
        if (iter != items.end())
            iter->quantity += quantity;
        else
            items.emplace_back(partCode, quantity);
    }

    double totalCost() const
    {
        double total = std::accumulate(items.begin(), items.end(), 0.0,
            [](double totalSoFar, const OrderItem &item) {
                return totalSoFar + (costOfPart(item.partCode) * item.quantity);
            }
        );
        // TOOD: fees, taxes, discounts, etc...
        return total;
    }
};

std::vector<Order> orders;

double costOfAllOrders()
{
    return std::accumulate(orders.begin(), orders.end(), 0.0,
        [](double totalSoFar, const Order &order){
            return totalSoFar + order.totalCost();
        }
    );
}

double costOfOrder(int orderCode)
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(orders.begin(), orders.end(),
        [=](Order &order){ return order.code == orderCode; }
    );
    if (iter != orders.end())
        return iter->totalCost();
    return 0.0;
}

...

parts.emplace_back('A', 10.0);
parts.emplace_back('B', 20.0);

...

Order order(12345);
order.addItem('A', 1);
orders.push_back(order);

...

double costOfOneOrder = costOfOrder(12345);
double totalCostOfOrders = costOfAllOrders();
...
```

---

**Update:** Based on the code you have added, you are looping all wrong.  You need something more like this instead:

```cpp
auto partCost = [&](char code) -> int {
    for(auto &p : partsVec) {
        if (p.code == code)
            return p.cost;
    }
    return 0;
}

int totalCost = 0;
for(auto &c : customers){
    totalCost += accumulate(c.partsList.begin(), c.partsList.end(), 0,
        [&](int totalSoFar, char code) {
            return totalSoFar + partCost(code);
        }
    );
}
```

Or, just using plain loops:

```cpp
void test(){
    int cost = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
        auto &c = customers[i];
        for(unsigned x = 0; x < c.partsList.size(); x++) {
            auto partCode = c.partsList[x];
            for(unsigned z = 0; z < partsVec.size(); z++) {
                auto &p = partsVec[z];
                if (p.code == partCode) {
                    cost += p.cost;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << cost << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will go and delete this question, and repost with my own code to make it "detailed enough".

Comment: @Hugs you don't need to delete this question.  Simply edit it instead to add more detail to it, then it can be reopened.

Comment: @Hugs I think you mean "edited **question**". I have updated MY answer.

Comment: @Hugs read the [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) docs for [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and the `op` parameter of the [`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Just find for every part in order it's cost from the parts container, that you pass to lambda in accumulate algorithm. I assume, that either order behaves as a container or each part in order can be obtained and put to a vector.

```cpp
std::accumulate(order.begin(), order.end(), 0, [&parts](const auto & o) {
    return std::find(parts.begin(), parts.end(), o).cost();
}
```

You may also try and write a "nasty" function object that will behave as a lambda.

```cpp
class AccumulatorHelper {
public:
    vector<Parts>& parts;
    AccumulatorHelper(vector<Parts>& p): parts(p) { }
    int operator()(const Order& order) {
        return std::find(parts.begin(), parts.end(), order.character());
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm fairly new, how do I go about doing this without a lambda please?

Comment: You may write a function object that behaves similarly to lambda. But I highly recommend use lambda in day to day code, only if you're working on lower version than C++03 or plain C.

Comment: Doesn't quite work, after the o can't get the actual cost :(

Comment: I just tried to convey a structure, where accumulate calls find with order value character. If you can't get the character() out of Order or cost() out of Part, you may consider to change interface in a respective class.